# Emacs : -fh (full height) question

Tags: linux, emacs, configuration, dot-emacs

Each time Emacs starts up, I'd like its window to take up the full height of my screen.

Now, from the man page, I found this could be done with the `-fh` switch.

It somewhat works, but is there a way I could do the following:

1) Specify the `-fh` option in `.emacs`, so I don't have to type it every time.

2) Make new frames (those you create with `C-x 5 2`, etc.) also obey this setting. Right now, even if I run `emacs -fh`, the new frames seem to completely ignore it.

Thanks.

Comment: well, there is always the option of running emacs in a terminal. Anyways, it's off topic here. This belongs to superuser.com

Comment: Yea, I thought so, but then I searched for emacs here and there were many similar (as in not programming per se) questions here, so I posted here.

Comment: Can't you alias emacs='emacs -fh'? If you want maximum usage of the screen, why not try a tiling window manager?

Comment: Yes, that's what I have now, actually, but it seems there should be a cleaner way (for example, I'd have to change the keyboard shortcuts too, etc., it would be more practical if this could be in .emacs). Also, that still wouldn't solve 2).. Anyway, you're right, maybe a tiling wm would solve this (I tried one once, then went back to openbox), I'll look into it more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
(add-to-list 'initial-frame-alist `(fullscreen . fullheight))
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist `(fullscreen . fullheight))
```

See [Section 29.3.2: Initial Frame Parameters](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Initial-Parameters.html).

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I needed. Sorry for waiting so long to accept, I was not at home for a few days.